# How can I make use of dnsMsg in golang's net package

Tags: go

I'm writing a simple golang application that needs to do some decoding of some DNS packets. I noticed that in the `net` library, there appears to be the perfect implementation in the form of `net/dnsmsg.go` which contains the right structs, pack / unpack functions etc.

However, the type is marked private (lower case `dnsMsg`). So it appears that I have no way of using this from within my app.

I'm quite new to golang, so don't know if my only option would be to reimplement `net/dnsmsg.go` myself, or if there's a better way around this.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but someone wrote a pretty comprehensive DNS library in Go: https://github.com/miekg/dns. Maybe you can use that for your application?

Comment: Turns out I was already using their pcap library. Good find - now switched to using that instead.

Comment: @growse Would you please answer your own question and accept it? It's still in "Unanswered" category..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by using a third party dns library, specifically miekg/dns (https://github.com/miekg/dns).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Google's [gopacket](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket) package which provides packets decoding for Go. In particular, the [layers](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket/layers) sub-package provides logic for decoding protocol packets, among which what is necessary to decode DNS packets.